# Why std::set / std::map and std::unordered_set / std::unordered_map does NOT have std::erase overload but have std::erase_if?

Tags: c++, c++20

`std::erase / std::erase_if` have overloads for all sequence containers (e.g.vector / array / list). But associative containers (e.g. set / map) only have `std::erase_if`. Anyone knows why?

[std::erase_if (std::set)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase_if)

[std::erase_if (std::unordered_set)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/erase_if)

Comment: I would guess it's related to the fact that sets can define equality in various ways but `erase` relies on `remove` which only uses `==`.

Comment: Yes, i also think it's about the `operator==`, which not used in set.

Answer (score 2):

Found this in the original proposal [N4009](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4009.htm)

> Design Decision #3: Just predicates, or also values?
> This is related
> to naming.  Providing eliminate(container, value) and
> eliminate_if(container, pred) would be perfectly acceptable.  However,
> providing erase(container, value) in addition to erase_if(container, pred)
> would be problematic, and has therefore been avoided in this proposal.
> **The problem is that the ordered/unordered associative containers have
> erase(key) member functions that perform efficient lookups.  This could lead
> to confusion about erase(container, value)'s complexity.  (It would have to be
> a linear scan, even for sets - erase(key) works with operator<() equivalence,
> but erase(container, value) would have to use operator==(), and they are not
> required to have any particular relationship.)  In contrast,
> erase_if(container, pred) "sounds like" linear complexity (which it is),
> even for ordered/unordered associative containers.**  And of course, lambdas
> (especially C++14's generic lambdas) make it relatively easy to use erase_if()
> to eliminate all occurrences of a given value.  Informally speaking
> (i.e. without hard data), I've found that having to erase all occurrences of
> a particular value is a much less common task than having to erase all
> elements that satisfy some condition.  On the other hand, symmetry would be
> desirable, and it would prevent users from wondering why one flavor
> was missing.